# EMUI 5.0 is displaying orange navbar and notification bar even battery saving is turn off

Tags: 7.0-nougat, notification-bar, navigation-bar

What is the possible other cause for this? I believe this one should not be orange. I tried to restart it, turn it off still got orange bars. Please no factory reset answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird, but I was able to remove it when I told google assistant to turn of power saving mode though in the settings it was already turned off.